# How to Truncate a large Integer in Python?

Tags: python-3.8, truncate

```
import uuid
class Bank:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.AccountNo=uuid.uuid1()

Cust1=Bank() 
print("Account No: ",Cust1.AccountNo.int)
```

Output:

```
Account No:  47957342272647865824751872785085784912
```

It gives a large Integer as Output but I only need the first 10. How do I remove the extra digits from the end?
I thought of doing something like this...

```
print("Account No: ",Cust1.AccountNo.int//100000000000000000000000000000)
```

But I was wondering if there's any other better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert it string (array of char) and slice it

```
str(value)[:10]
```